# Configure Nagios alert in Tivoli dashboard(omnibus/netcool) integrated portal

Tags: dashboard, nagios, network-monitoring, tivoli

Im new to Tivoli Omnibus/netcool integrated portal,rightnow we are receiving server alerts ,DU alerts,Memory alerts through Nagios. we need to set it up in Tivoli Dashboard.Any ideas how to configure the nagios alerts in tivoli dashboard.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Is there any solution which will allow me to forward 
Nagios alerts to Netcool?

Comment: If I recall correctly, Nagios is possible to do this by sending SNMP traps (when an alarm coours) to Netcool using NET-SNMP, so you can use the Mttrapd probe to receive the alerts to ObjectServer.

Answer (score 0):

...what? Could you explain a bit better what you are trying to achieve? If you just want to display the nagios monitoring pages in the TIP, you can create a custom page with the properties to external URL. If you want to integrate the nagios chart to TIP's Dashboard, best thing to do is contact IBM support - they are well versed in how to solve integrate issues...